How to apply Regexp rule only for files with concrete names in Checkstyle
I have a regexp rule:
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="Regexp">
    ...
    </module>
  </module>

And I want to use this rule only for concrete files, for example, only for package-info.java. Could anyone say how to do it?

Can you clarify what “concrete names” and “concrete files” mean?  What are some examples of files that are not concrete?  I was guessing you meant abstract classes versus non-abstract classes, but you say that package-info.java is an example of a concrete file, so I am not clear on what qualifies a file as “concrete.”

@VGR "package-info.java", "module-info.java" are examples of concrete file names. If the word "concrete" bothers you, then just ignore it.

https://checkstyle.org/checks/regexp/regexp.html#Regexp
There is no way to restrict files to be processed by RegExp through its own configuration.
You will need to utilize a suppression ( https://checkstyle.org/filters/index.html ) to ignore the violations which you deem are unwanted.
Here is one example:
https://checkstyle.org/filters/suppressionsinglefilter.html#Example2-config
